# Should I do a STEM PhD with my own funds?

Tags: phd, advisor, funding

I have lost my TA position in a US public university after my first year. I was not kicked out but lost my funding due to poor TA performance. I got a 4 GPA and As in all my assignments.

My family is not millionaire but my mother and grandmother offered me to pay my tuition (19k a year) plus living expenses (10k for a 9 month academic period). They have a small profitable business in Latin America. Yes I am a foreigner. They told me I MUST finish what I started; otherwise, I will not be able to do anything in the future.

But I have contacted my advisor and he told me that even though I am allowed to continue the PhD with my own funding, the graduate committee is still a little upset with me because of my poor performance.

How should I approach the committee? Will they make my studies more trouble and more difficult?

On the other hand, my advisor and many people say it is not a good idea to pay for a US PhD.

I really want to finish that program, not only for my family support and encouragement. I also like my research field, though my university is not well known and all grad students are funded by TAships. No one has an RAship in my program.

If I don't have to be a TA, will that help me produce better research?

Anyway, I do not intend to get a US tenure position anyway. I will probably end up with running the business of my mother and grand mother in my country. But I do really love science and my field.

Comment: We can't make a decision for you, we can't predict the future actions of the graduate committee, and we can't predict your future research productivity, so what exactly are you asking us?

Comment: You lost your funding because of your bad TA performance, but a PhD is all about research. I cannot understand why the committee would be upset if your research was going fine? Not being a TA will give you more time to do research.

Comment: @user18244 First year Ph.D in the US was almost certainly all coursework, no research work.